# Laravel Timeout Issue

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a long running Laravel process to generate a report. When selecting long date ranges, I was getting a redirect back to the same URL after approximately 100s. I changed the code to this:

```
set_time_limit(20);
while(1) {
    $var = 3 + 4 / 11;
}
```

It runs for 20s then redirects to the same URL. I'd like to add that I have 2 routes, a GET route, and a POST route. The timeout happens for the POST route.

I've tried

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

but it didn't make a difference. I've turned on debug, but nothing. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I am running PHP 5.4.x so its not safe mode.
EDIT: here is the controller - http://laravel.io/bin/WVdVz, Here is the last code that is supposed to execute - http://laravel.io/bin/aa2GW.
EDIT: The error handling library, Whoops, catches and logs timeout errors. My logs are clean. This has something to do with how Laravel is treating responses after my _download function...

Comment: Is your controller handling the redirect back to the same page on purpose, under some circumstances? Any debug input? Are you sure it's timeout related and not memory limit related? just throwing some random thoughts...

Comment: @alou My controller is supposed to generate an XLS spreadsheet download. The last thing the controller does is this function - http://laravel.io/bin/aa2GW. The controller finishes with "return;". I've tried bumping the memory to 640MB. Either way I find it interesting that it would redirect to the same URL using GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I figured it out. Apache was timing out. Apparently, when Apache times out, it throws a 500 response code. Apparently (again), when a browser gets a 500 error code to a POST request, it resends it as a GET request. I wrote it up here in more detail: http://blog.voltampmedia.com/2014/09/02/php-apache-timeouts-post-requests/

To be clear, its not a Laravel issue. Do note that the Whoops library does capture the timeout error.